# Flow of program- requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

This JS code when run gives an output. Shouldn't this lead to infinite recursive calls and hence show Time Limit Exceeded? Pls explain the flow of program.

```
function main(ctime){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
    if(start==undefined){
        start= ctime;
    }
    if((ctime-start)/1000<0.5){
        console.log(ctime);
        return;
    } 
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no recursion here. `window.requestAnimationFrame(main);` just puts the `main` in the callback queue without executing or waiting it (like `setTimeout()` does) and returns immediately, then the next line is executed.